# How to use FirebaseCrashlytics.Instance.RecordException in Xamarin / C#?

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.android, crashlytics

To use Firebase Crashlytics I have done the following for my Xamarin / Android project:

- Registered app on Firebase
- Added google-services.json to project
- Installed Nuget package Xamarin.Firebase.Crashlytics 118.0.1
- Added `<string name="com.google.firebase.crashlytics.mapping_file_id">none</string>` to strings

I am a bit confused about the next step for actually recording the crash. I have read that there is no need to initialise anything and to use the function `FirebaseCrashlytics.Instance.RecordException` but I don't understand what I am actually supposed to put in the parameter, or where to use the function. I have tried looking at the samples on Git but they don't appear to be using this function anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no documentation on how to use package [Xamarin.Firebase.Crashlytics](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.Crashlytics/118.0.1), and developers have to rely on the official Firebase documentation to implement it.

However there is a procedure about this summaried by some developer ,you can check it here: https://github.com/a-imai/XamarinCrashlyticsUpgradeSample .

The main steps are as follows:

- Install necessary packages;
- Reinstall google-service.json;
- Use `com.google.firebase.crashlytics.mapping_file_id`;
- Removed `firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled` from
  `AndroidManifest.xml`

For more details, you can check above documents.